# C# get generic type arguments from within the executed generic method without directly referencing them, i.e. typeof(T0)

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to get generic type arguments from within the executed generic method **without directly referencing them (i.e. typeof(T0))**? For example:

```cs
public static List<(T0?, T1?, T2?, T3?, T4?)> ParseParameter<T0, T1, T2, T3, T4>(this JArray array, params string[] columnCodesCaseIndependent)
{
    var genericArgs = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()!.GetGenericArguments();
    
    // ...

    return result;
}
```

Testing the above in debugger I see:

0. {Name="T0", FullName=null}
1. same as above for the rest

So the types are not the ones actually used. net5.0

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ParseParameter<double, string, ...>("doublecol", "stringcol", ...). I was hoping to get the array of types without having to call typeof(T0), typeof(T1), ...